# "We're booking your holiday" v.s. "we're booking in your holiday"

Tags: grammar

I'm writing a page loading message for a holiday website. After the customer enters their payment details and clicks the 'pay now' button, it takes a few minutes to process the booking so we're showing this loading message to let them know of the system status.

The loading message reads: "Please wait, we're booking **in** your holiday."

This message sounds a bit odd but I can't quite figure out if there's something wrong with my grammar or tone.

The alternative is: "Please wait, we're booking your holiday."

Which is more appropriate for this context, and why.

Comment: You should say what country your audience is in. As an American, just using the word *booking* makes it sound somewhat British (or Kiwi or Aussie or ...) to me.

Comment: "Please wait while we finalise your booking."

Comment: Good point @ThePhoton the audience's country is Australia

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The verb *book* (in this sense) is transitive: it takes a direct object, the event (holiday etc) that is being booked. *In* is not needed, and may confuse your readers.

OED definition for "book" v:

> (3b)  *transitive*. To accept a reservation from (a passenger, guest, etc.) in advance of a journey, stay, etc.; to issue a ticket for travel to, or assign a reserved room, seat, etc., to; frequently in passive.